# Как сделать точно такие же namespace?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть вот такой корневой узел:

```
<Project z:Id="i1" xmlns="http://blablabla/datacontracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
```

Не могу понять, как в XDocument создать namespace `z:Id="i1"`

Все остальные пространства создаются без проблем...

```
var dns = XNamespace.Get("http://blablabla/datacontracts");
    var prjElement=new XElement(dns + "Project");      
    prjElement.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "z", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"));
    prjElement.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"));
```

Как мне добиться цели?

Comment: А как в документации пробовали? В самом низу, как раз ваша ситуация. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnamespace